# How can I do this SQL query (aggregate group by and where in clause)?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the over simplified version of the problem, where I have 5 tables: Project (~50K), Organization (~20K), Category, Bidder (~250K), Rating

```
Project (
    id, 
    owner_id (Organization.id),
    title
)

Organization (
    id,
    name
)

Category (
    id,
    name
)

Bidder (
    id,
    organization_id (Organization.id),
    project_id (Project.id)
    category_id (Category.id),
    is_winner
)

Rating (
    id,
    bidder_a_id (Bidder.id),
    bidder_b_id (Bidder.id),
    bidder_a_is_winner,
    bidder_b_is_winner
)
```

There are Organizations that bid on a Project in a Category. The bidders can win or lose their bid on a Project and a Rating is then calculated (number of wins / total). The Rating is calculated between an Organization and another (or more than one).

For example:

1. we would like to show the rating for all the bidders of a project including only the bids on projects where the same organization as the owner of the project was also implied.
2. we would like to show the rating for all the bidders in a category of a project including only the bids on projects where other selected organizations were also implied.

I understand that the Rating table would not be necessary to get a result, but because of the amount of data, it would take too much time to execute the query. Therefore, I created the Rating table to hold the association of the bidders working on the same project. There might not be a Rating between two bidders if they never worked together before.

I will try to update with my own take, but I cannot seem to make it work yet... I am losing the bidders in the results when they do not have a Rating and I filter with a IN clause for the selected organizations.

**Edit:** I found a way around my problem. I added a column to my inner query with that returns a boolean if the current row is IN the selected organizations. When I do the SUM, the ones that are NOT IN, are not counted in the calculation of the Ratings.

In summary, when I tried with an HAVING clause, it would eliminate the rows that had no Rating, but I still wanted them in the final result. I wanted to know they were 0.

Comment: Have you tried using `HAVING` in order to implement a `WHERE` type filter AFTER aggregating with GROUP BY?

Comment: hard to understand your query, but try to remove the IN clause and make it an OUTER JKOIN instead

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry, I will remember for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looked something like this (notice the use of IN clause inside the SELECT):

```
select
    org.id,
    sum(sub.nb_wins),
    sum(sub.nb_total),
    sum(sub.nb_wins) / sum(sub.nb_total)
from
    (select 
        bid.id as bidder_id,
        bid.category_id as category_id,
        sum(
            case rat.id is not null or rat.bidder_a_id in (...) then bid.is_winner else 0
        ) as nb_wins, 
        sum(
            case rat.id is not null or rat.bidder_a_id in (...) then 1 else 0
        ) as nb_total

    from
        Bidder bid
            left outer join
        Rating rat on rat.bidder_b_id = bid.id

    group by
        bid.id,
        bid.category_id) as sub
        inner join
    Organization org on org.id = sub.bidder_id

group by
    sub.bidder_id,
    sub.category_id
```